# Keeping strings in a login dialog window when orientation change. Android

Tags: android, string, dialog, onchange, screen-orientation

I'm trying to keep what users typed in my login dialog window when orientation changing, but i always receive this error message:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object
>   reference.

There's the code:

public class ReservationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView uDeM_Logo;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reservation);

    uDeM_Logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.UdeM_Logo);

    dimensions();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    RelativeLayout login = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);

    EditText userField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
    EditText passField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.passEditText);
    String user = userField.getText().toString();
    String pass = passField.getText().toString();

    outState.putString("User", user);
    outState.putString("Pass", pass);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout login = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);

    EditText userField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
    EditText passField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.passEditText);
    String user = savedInstanceState.getString("User");
    String pass = savedInstanceState.getString("Pass");

    userField.setText(user);
    passField.setText(pass);
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration nouvOrient) {
    if(nouvOrient.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ||
    nouvOrient.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        dimensions();
}

public void dimensions() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point grandeur = new Point();
    display.getSize(grandeur);
    double hauteur = grandeur.y, dim = hauteur * 0.2492;
    int dimsInt = (int) dim;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams parametres = uDeM_Logo.getLayoutParams();
    parametres.width = dimsInt;
    parametres.height = dimsInt;

    uDeM_Logo.setLayoutParams(parametres);


}

public void loginDialog(View log){
    final Dialog login = new Dialog(this);
    login.setContentView(R.layout.login_dialog);

    Button btnLogin = (Button)login.findViewById(R.id.dialogLoginBtn);
    Button btnCancel = (Button)login.findViewById(R.id.dialogCancelBtn);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ReservationActivity.this,
                    "Login Sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login.dismiss();
        }
    });

    login.show();
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you do not need to recreate the activity on orientation change. You can just set this configuration for your activity in your `manifest`.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do that in `onRestoreInstanceState()`

```
 RelativeLayout login = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);
 EditText userField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
 EditText passField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.passEditText);
```

But instead make these `login`, `userField`, `passField` a field variables in your Activity class as follows:

```
private RelativeLayout login;
private EditText userField, passField;
```

Also move the above 3 code lines from `onSaveInstanceState()` to `onCreate()` but modify them to work with your field variables as follows:

```
 login = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);
 userField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
 passField = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.passEditText);
```

**And** I recommend you to restore state at `onCreate()` instead of `onRestoreInstanceState()` as follows:

```
// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore value of members from saved state
    String user = savedInstanceState.getString("User");
    String pass = savedInstanceState.getString("Pass");
    userField.setText(user);
    passField.setText(pass);
} else {
    // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
}
```

The reason is because `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called after `onStart()`, whereas `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`